# yum list installed|grep <rpm name> not executing as jboss user

Tags: linux, jboss, redhat, rpm, yum

I have 2 hosts where the above command runs fine with jboss user and for the other hosts it fails giving me

TEST $ yum list installed | grep

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "/usr/bin/yum", line 29, in

```
yummain.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True)
```

File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 285, in user_main

```
errcode = main(args)
```

File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 105, in main

```
    base.getOptionsConfig(args)
```

File "/usr/share/yum-cli/cli.py", line 228, in getOptionsConfig

```
    self.conf
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/**init**.py", line 891, in

```
    conf = property(fget=lambda self: self._getConfig(),
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/**init**.py", line 299, in _getConfig

```
    startupconf = config.readStartupConfig(fn, root)
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/config.py", line 884, in readStartupConfig

```
       startupconf.uuid = get_uuid(uuidfile)
```

File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/misc.py", line 1030, in get_uuid

```
      return open(savepath, 'r').read()

   IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '///var/lib/yum/uuid'
```

any help would be appreciable if this command can be run.

Comment: You can only run that command as `root`.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried with same  with root privileges?

It could be permission issue .

If you mention distro and version it would be good . Try below

yum clean all

yum update

restart the box .

If you are getting error with yum update then run

rm -f /var/lib/rpm/__db*
rpm --rebuilddb

Comment: didn't work.... I tried changing the permissions of the repo files and run the yum list it worked but failed after displaying few rpms. Now giving me

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/rpmsack.py", line 1794, in _read
    info = misc.stat_f(fn)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/misc.py", line 918, in stat_f
    return os.stat(filename)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/yum/yumdb/x/fe72ba1760a75f6d8240506807cf9960ae9a3ba0-xcb-util-0.3.6-1.el6-x86_64/from_repo'

Comment: Check teh answers please .. everyone is pointing it could be permissions issue. Please check user / group permissions . Why dont you try it with different user who has root privileges ? So that you can confirm it is something wrong with that user ( permissions kinda)...

Answer (score 0):

most likely you are having problems with user (uid) or group (gid) permissions executing yum. On the boxes that are working, look at the current groups `jboss` belongs to with `grep jboss /etc/group`. Then compare the groups in which jboss is a member to the same information on the box where it is not working. If you see a difference, then you can add jboss to the needed group with `groupmod -A user group` Note: some distributions use `gpasswd` instead of `groupmod` to add users to groups. You will also need `root` permission to add jboss to any new groups. If you have `sudo` access, then you can simply do `sudo groupmod -A jboss whatevergroup`

Comment: groups are same for user jboss.